# Which preposition to use: "This is an extension of/to the package"

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct usage of here:

> *extension **to** a package*

or

> *extension **of** a package*

What would be the difference?

**Edit**

I am using it as follows: *This is an extension **of**/**to** the package*

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Hamza! It depends on the context. "We've added an extension **to** a package we had earlier created". "Extension **of** a package is (a?) hard work requiring advanced programming skills". The first usage seems to be more widespread, but still you'd better add more context.

Comment: @CopperKettle I have included the context.

Comment: The context is still not very clear, in my opinion. Consider these two examples from [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/extension): *He has applied for permission to build a single-storey extension to his house; the further extension of state control*. They suggest subtle difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are virtually the same in meaning, that something is **added** to increase functionality.

**Of** has a certain possessive quality about it so :

> extension **of** a package

would mean that there is **an existing package** and the people that created the package have added something to it

> Windows 10 is an **extension of** the Windows Operating system series.

whereas :

> extension **to** a package

would have the connotation of something being **bolted-on**, **in addition to** the existing package

> Third-party disk optimisers are **extensions to** the base operating system.

Comment: Well, the extension is of/to a package which already exists and is not created by me.

Comment: If it's **your** extension, then you would say: "I have created an extension **to** *the something* package" or "I have created an extension **for** *the something* package".